# Setting up a subdomain on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, subdomain

I have a dev server for my C# Web Application and to access the dev site I go to the server name in my browser (lfi-fsxmv06) and I can access my web application.  Now I want to set up a subdomain of that (test.lfi-fsxmv06) is this possible?

My bindings on the dev site (lfi-fsxmv06) are http with port 80 and ip address *, and the hostname is blank.

My bindings on the subdomain site are http, port 80, IP adddress *, and the hostname is test.lfi-fsxmv06 however if I try t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply add an CNAME or alias record in your local network's DNS server to point test.lfi-fsxmv06 to lfi-fsxmv06.

Alternatively on the machine you are using to test the site, alter the local hosts file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) and add an entry in there for the server.